# How to solve PLS-00103 Oracle PLSQL error?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I got an error

> PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END" when expecting one of the following:
> ( begin case declare exit for goto if loop mod null raise
> return select update while with 
>   <<
> continue close current delete fetch lock insert open rollback
> savepoint set sql execute commit forall merge standard pipe
> purge json_object

**Here is my code:**

```
declare
    a int := 4;
    i int;
begin
    for i in 1..10 loop
        dbms_output.put_line(i);
        if i=a then
            goto ax;
        end if;
    end loop;
    <<ax>>
end;
```

Comment: it is expecting a statement, for example dbms_output. Plus try to use exit instead of GOTO, to exit the loop.
When PL/SQL encounters a GOTO statement, it transfers control to the first executable statement after the label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-control-statements.html#GUID-7C14CDED-B86F-4496-A1F6-8C3B67E3B032):

> A label can appear only before a block (as in Example 4-21) or before a statement (as in Example 4-29), not in a statement, as in Example 4-30.

As you can see in the examples, you can fix this by adding a null statement:

```
declare
    a int := 4;
    --i int;
begin
    for i in 1..10 loop
        dbms_output.put_line(i);
        if i=a then
            goto ax;
        end if;
    end loop;
    <<ax>>
    null;
end;
/
```

In this case you can also just use `exit` instead of `goto`:

```
declare
    a int := 4;
    --i int;
begin
    for i in 1..10 loop
        dbms_output.put_line(i);
        if i=a then
            exit;
        end if;
    end loop;
end;
/
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Bc2Y4KyV)

In both cases I've commented out the declaration of `i` - you don't need to declare a loop variable, and even if you do the scope is different so they would be independent.